# Binding to NSArrayController's arrangedObjects shows an open parenthesis

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding, key-value-observing, nsarraycontroller

I have an NSArrayController bound to my mutable model array via its `contentArray` binding. And I have a few controls (like an inspector) where I want to show some of the properties of the objects in my array. I bound the controls' value to `arrangedObjects.property` of my NSArrayController.

When I add an object to my model array, all the controls show a single opening parenthesis `(`. If I bind the controls to `selection.property` instead and make the NSArrayController select all the objects all the time, it works. But I was wondering why it didn't work with arrangedContent? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What controls are you binding to the array controller?  The various controls do different things with their bindings.

The open parenthesis is the first line of an array's `description`. The control is expecting a string and is obtaining one from the bound thing by invoking `-description`.

Comment: I'm using text fields. Do you have any idea why it would get the array's description, if I bound the controls' value to arrayObjects.someProperty (an NSString property)?  (And if it does, why only the first character?).

Comment: `-[NSArray valueForKey:]` returns an array built by invoking `-valueForKey:` on each element. So, the key path "arrangedObjects.someProperty" is an array of strings if `someProperty` is a string property. What is it you expect it to mean when you bind a text field's value to an array controller? What should the text field contain when the array has no items or multiple items? (It's not the first characters, it's the first line. Try selecting all from the text field and pasting into a text editor.)

Comment: Well, I would expect it to show the property (if it's the same for all the objects in the array). Or show a placeholder "Multiple Values" when there are multiple different values. And this is exactly what happens if I bind the text fields to selection.someProperty (and making the array controller select every object at all times). And I don't see why there would be any difference between that and simply using arrangedObjects.someProperty.

Comment: The `selection` property is special. Read the docs on it and how it differs from `selectedObjects`.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks. So is there no easy way to bind to a whole array like that?

Comment: I had the same issue. In case somebody lands here via Google, my problem was that I switched to an NSArrayController later but still had the table's `Content` binding bound to the array as well.